# How to find out the path that crosses the maximum number of custom markers on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps

The problematic:

- I have 100 markers on a map, that exist in a rural area with lots of roads in between
- Given a start point (marker), I need to find THE PATH (directions) that passes near the MOST number of other markers
- By "near" I would specify a distance between the road and the marker, if the distance exceeds 50 meters, the marker does not count
- Knowing that a path starts at our start point and ends at a radius of 5 kilometers in any direction

The result would be a simple path drawn on the map, (Web: ASP.Net w/ JS *or* Win: C# WinForms) but not representing the shortest path, nor the less time consuming path, but the one that meets our conditions above.

As I'm completely new to Google Maps, and searching the forums didn't lead me anywhere, If you can guide me through choosing the right API, the coding platform, and link me to code snippets and samples that can help me build my script, it would be much appreciated!!!

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: when you want to get directions from the google maps api you need to specify starting point, ending point and waypoints. waypoints are optional and returned path goes as close to the waypoints as possible. however, with google maps you can only specify up to 8 waypoints.